# Knockout Audio Playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'm creating a music-based app that uses Knockout for it's bindings. All of the tracks listed in the app are pulled externally from Soundcloud like so:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.soundcloud.com/users/guy-j/tracks.json?client_id=c4bc3b1a93902abecbaca3fa4582d970', {limit: 200}, function(data) {
            vm.tracks($.map(data, function (track) {
                return {
                    artwork: track.artwork_url,
                    avatar: track.user.avatar_url,
                    date: track.created_at,
                    description: track.description,
                    duration: track.duration,
                    listens: track.playback_count,
                    permalink: track.permalink_url,
                    purhcase: track.purchase_url,
                    stream: track.stream_url,
                    track: track.title
                };
            }));
        });
```

These tracks (once fetched) are pushed into a blank observableArray and the HTML view is then bound to that array and generates a list of tracks. I've got the audio playing/pausing like so:

To select/play a track, each `<li>` that's generated from the observableArray has a click handler called 'goToTrack' which then passes an observable called 'self.chosenTrackData' the selected track and my audio element is then bound with 'chosenTrackData' to play the chosen track.

My problem now lies with the fact that I'm not quite sure what the best way to approach the next/prev track features using Knockout would be. I'd have to some how distinguish the current point in the observableArray and then ++ or -- depending which option you've selected?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm still learning Knockout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest keeping an internal "current track" number that you increment or decrement and base a computed on that.

```
function PlayerViewModel() {
    var self = this,
        currentTrackNo = ko.observable(0);

    // data
    self.tracks = ko.observableArray();

    // computeds
    self.currentTrack = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.tracks()[currentTrackNo()];
    });
    self.hasTrack = function (track) {
        return !!self.currentTrack();
    };
    self.hasNextTrack = ko.computed(function () {
        return currentTrackNo() < self.tracks().length - 1;
    });
    self.hasPrevTrack = ko.computed(function () {
        return currentTrackNo() > 0;
    });

    // API
    self.setNextTrack = function () {
        if (self.hasNextTrack()) {
            currentTrackNo(currentTrackNo() + 1);
        }
    };
    self.setPrevTrack = function () {
        if (self.hasPrevTrack()) {
            currentTrackNo(currentTrackNo() - 1);
        }
    };
    self.setTrack = function (track) {
        var trackNo = ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.tracks(), track);
        currentTrackNo(trackNo);
    };

    // init
    $.getJSON('...', {limit: 200}); etc;
}
```

Bind your "current track" view component to the `currentTrack` observable. Make sure that you use `hasTrack` in some way (as `currentTrack` might be undefined).

---

Alternative implementation, avoiding the maintenance of a separate track number:

```
function PlayerViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    // data
    self.tracks = ko.observableArray();
    self.currentTrack = ko.observable();

    // computeds
    self.currentTrackNo = ko.computed(function () {
        var currentTrack = self.currentTrack();
        return ko.utils.arrayIndexOf(self.tracks(), currentTrack);
    });
    self.hasTrack = function (track) {
        return !!self.currentTrack();
    };
    self.hasNextTrack = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.currentTrackNo() < self.tracks().length - 1;
    });
    self.hasPrevTrack = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.currentTrackNo() > 0;
    });

    // API
    self.setNextTrack = function () {
        if (self.hasNextTrack()) {
            self.currentTrack(self.tracks()[self.currentTrackNo() + 1]);
        }
    };
    self.setPrevTrack = function () {
        if (self.hasPrevTrack()) {
            self.currentTrack(self.tracks()[self.currentTrackNo() - 1]);
        }
    };
    self.setTrack = function (track) {
        // make sure that track is actually in self.tracks here
        self.currentTrack(track);
    };

    // init
    $.getJSON('...', {limit: 200}); etc;
}
```

Comment: @leaksterrr The alternative would be to not to use an index but to have a `currentTrack` observable and use `ko.utils.arrayIndexOf()` in your `setNextTrack()`/`setPrevTrack` methods directly. Maybe that's even better, because it would allow for dynamically sorted track lists - the next/prev tracks would always be correct in the current sort order.

Comment: So when I add filters and search to the app, playing the next track will be playing the next track in the filter and not the next track in the array? What would be the best way to go about refactoring the above to reflect this? I'm still relatively a newb to KO.

Comment: Yes. The implementation is actually quite similar. See modified answer. You'd have to implement some guards that make sure there's always one "current" track  (i.e. auto-select the first track of a newly loaded list) and react to an empty track list (i.e. remove the old "current" track). The same goes for filters. In short: You have to makes sure that your app behaves sensibly when the current track is not on the list for whatever reason.